# Writing sub-sections using Matlab publish markup

Tags: matlab

I want to create a Matlab markup using publish. I am using "showCode = false" because I do not want to print the entire code, only what I write with comments, and all the plots.

One thing that I want to do is have a cover page, sections, and sub-sections. Here are two questions:

(1) Sub-sections:
I understand sections start with two percent signs: %% SECTION NAME
How can I write sub-sections within this section?

(2) Is it possible to have a document cover page using publish?

Thanks

Monica

Answer (score 3):

With regard to sub-sections, you can add them using [HTML Markup](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-1), but this won't be added to the Contents menu generated from the [section titles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btfv_lg-1). For a cover page, you could add an [external graphic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5juu-1) (note: you'll want to put the image files in the folder with your published output and link to there). Here's a sample script illustrating both of the above:

```
%% Title
%
% <<C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\peppers.png>>
%
% Description.

%% Section 1
% Some text.

%% Section 2
% Some more text.

%%
% <html><h3>Sub-section</h3></html>
%
% Some subtext.

%% Section 3
% Final text.
```

And here's the published HTML output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks gnovice! This works for html output, but not so far for pdf.

Comment: @shadowfax: Which part doesn't work? The subsections or images? For a PDF, you may only be allowed to use certain image types, BMP and JPG I think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MATLAB publishing markup is very basic and I don't think you can do sub-sections easily.

Within the publish markup the only option I can think of is to include `<h2>` `<h3>` markup within a `<html>` block. Which isn't that easy to setup in the code.

Anything more complex eg. for item (2) then I suspect you will have to use the MATLAB report generator.
https://uk.mathworks.com/products/ML_reportgenerator.html

Comment: Thanks Adrian, regarding using <include>filename.m</include>, does that work for a "pdf" document? I could not make it work for publishing to pdf, so not sure if the way I was doing is correct.